# Autolayout (greater then or equal) option still create constraint (equal)

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I created a container (UIView *) in my view controller's view using the story board and I set the container height constraint to be **grater then or equal** but after that I get two constraints, one that is a **greater then** *user constraint* and another **equal height** that isn't a user constraint, therefore can't be deleted. Why this behaviour?

I'm asking this because I'm getting this log error

```
 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
 Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
 (2) find   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
 (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand,
 refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa49af60 V:[UIView:0xa4a9300(30)]>",
```

...

which shows that the fixed height still exists although I have a **greater then** constraint.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your storyboard with the relevant constraints showing, and also (more important) the full list of constraints from the exception. If IB is still adding constraints, you haven't specified enough of your own.

Comment: I don't know why you get that error, but you get the equal constraint because a greater than or equal to constraint is not usually enough to unambiguously define a view's size and position.